# Chrome extension storage onChanged() not detecting changes (not firing)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I've seen this question asked on here before, but there was never really a proper answer. So I have a listener registered on `background.js` to listen on `chrome.storage.onChanged`. However, as far as I can tell it's not firing the event despite changes to storage. The change happens from the `popup.js` file when the user clicks a button.

I have set up a polling button to get the latest data from storage and updates are showing there, but the `console.log` calls from the methods listening never get called.

The same item in the storage is being updated, i.e. there are no new items being added or removed. However, I have tested adding different items and it still doesn't fire.

Inside `background.js`

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function() {
    console.log("hehe");
});
```

Inside `popup.js`

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({"databases": dbList}, function () {
            console.log("Successfully added: " + domain);
            document.getElementById("add-remove").innerText = remove;
            setForRemove(dbList, domain)
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: Nah I have console up and running, this is how I'm verifying that items are actually be saved to storage

Comment: There are different consoles for each component of the extension. You need to open a separate one as shown in the linked topic.

Answer (score 0):

Which manifest are you using? I've tried real hard to make storage listener to work:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(() => {
    console.log("tick");
});
```

with Manifest v3, but it did not work, even before the service worker got inactive.

After switching to Manifest v2, everything worked smoothly. I am not discouraging using Manifest v3, you should try to make it work as it is recommended way now, but if it is does not work no matter what just like in my case, I don't see any other way than to use older Manifest.